# Skrollr relative positions not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I need to be able to move a div from one 100% height div to a fixed position in  another 100% height div. I am using relative positions as I will not know how big the div is. What exactly am I doing wrong, the Skrollr documentation confuses me. Here is the code I am using to try and solve my issue.

```
data-0="transform: translate(0,0vh);" data-center="transform: translate(0,100vh);
```

Here is a reduced test case:
http://codepen.io/simonfricker/pen/KVmPaZ

**HTML**

```
<section class="block hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="happy" data-0="transform: translate(0,0vh);" data-top-top="transform: translate(0,10vh);"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="block content">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Happy face should end up here on scroll</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
  height:100% !important; 
}

.block{
height:100%;
}

.hero{
  background: red;
}

.content{
  background: yellow;
      text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.happy{
  font-size:250px;
  text-align: center;
}
p{
line-height:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
var s = skrollr.init();
```

Comment: While external resources like CodePen and JSFiddle are useful, the content stored there may (will) eventually disappear, making this question useless for future visitors.  You must include sufficient detail here so the question and any answers remain useful in the future.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have included the code